# Left shift values in a TensorArray in Tensorflow v1.15

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to left shift values in a `TensorArray` using another `TensorArray`, using the following code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

an_array = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=2, dynamic_size=False, clear_after_read=False, element_shape=(1, 2), name="First")
old_array = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=2, dynamic_size=False, clear_after_read=False, element_shape=(1, 2), name="Second")
old_array = old_array.write(0, 2.*tf.ones((1, 2)))
old_array = old_array.write(1, 3.*tf.ones((1, 2)))
for _ in range(1, 5):
    val = tf.random.normal(shape=(1, 2))
    an_array = an_array.write(0, old_array.read(1))
    an_array = an_array.write(1, val)
    old_array = an_array.identity()
print(tf.Session().run([an_array.stack(), old_array.stack()]))
```

I load the `old_array` with some initial values. In the loop I read the second element of the `old_array` array and give it to the first element of the `an_array` array. The new value is then written to the second element of the `an_array` array. The contents of `an_array` are copied over to `old_array`.

Though in the first iteration, the first element in `an_array` is strictly not the left shifted version of the array, but something based on the initial conditions, later iterations are expected to give the left shifted version of the `an_array` array.

When I run this script, I get the error

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: TensorArray First_1: Could not write to TensorArray index 0 because it has already been written to.

Can someone point out what is wrong with the code? Thanks.

Comment: Your code works on my machine. What's your tensorflow version?

Comment: @Kalpit tfv1.15

Comment: @Kalpit what version of tf are you on?

Comment: I'm on tf v1.14

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error as you are getting on running the code in `tensorflow version 1.15.2`. But it worked fine in `tensorflow version 2.2.0`. Seems like `tensorflow version 1.15.2` issue.

Below are the run results for tensorflow version 2.2.0.

**Tensorflow 2.2.0 -**

```
#%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
print(tf.__version__)

an_array = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=2, dynamic_size=False, clear_after_read=False, element_shape=(1, 2), name="First")
old_array = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=2, dynamic_size=False, clear_after_read=False, element_shape=(1, 2), name="Second")
old_array = old_array.write(0, 2.*tf.ones((1, 2)))
old_array = old_array.write(1, 3.*tf.ones((1, 2)))
for _ in range(1, 5):
    val = tf.random.normal(shape=(1, 2))
    an_array = an_array.write(0, old_array.read(1))
    an_array = an_array.write(1, val)
    old_array = an_array.identity()

print(tf.compat.v1.Session().run([an_array.stack(), old_array.stack()]))
```

**Output -**

```
2.2.0
[array([[[ 0.6800341 , -0.72848713]],

       [[ 0.6648014 , -0.40344566]]], dtype=float32), array([[[ 0.6800341 , -0.72848713]],

       [[ 0.6648014 , -0.40344566]]], dtype=float32)]
```

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.